# How do I get an acceptable last modified timestamp for my Jekyll site using a shell script?

Tags: sed, timestamps

I would like to be able to provide last modified timestamps to my Jekyll posts and pages using a shell script. The problem is that I do not know how to automatically generate an acceptable timestamp. The closest I have come to acceptable timestamp is using this command:

```
stat <FILE> | sed -n -e 's/Modify:\s//p'
```

which returns for my glossary.md file:

```
2016-02-12 09:37:55.393936224 +1000
```

this is almost the format I want. The only problem is I would like to remove the decimal `.393936224` from it. I thought I could manage this myself using `sed` but all my attempts have failed. Most of my attempts involved writing this output to a text file and then using sed on this text file to remove the decimal. I would prefer any answer you give to not write the output of this to a text file, although I would like the output of your solution to be writable to a variable. e.g., if the variable is `L`:

```
L=$(stat <FILE> | sed -n -e 's/Modify:\s//p' | sed ...)
```

where `| sed ...` can be replaced with whatever your solution to this problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date` (at least in the GNU implementation common today) can take the modification time of a file directly:

```
> date -r ~/.bashrc +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z'
2015-11-10 18:50:49 +0100
```

(or whatever format you desire)